# Center label with checkbox when several lines using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a checkbox with a label that sometimes are more than one line. How do I align the first line center to the checkbox

```
<label class="inline-block">
<input class="ml-2 mr-1 mb-1 inline-block" data-id="{{inputDataId}}" type="checkbox" class="{{class}}" {% if required %} required {% endif %}>
<span class="text-sm inline-block">
  {{label}}
</span>
</label>
```

I only get it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Tailwind solution***

**Using Tailwing, you should get the result you want with this:**

```
<label class="flex">
<input class="ml-2 mr-1 mb-1 mt-1 inline-block" data-id="{{inputDataId}}" type="checkbox" class="{{class}}" {% if required %} required {% endif %}>
<span class="text-sm inline-block">
 sdfsd fsd fsd fsdfds fsdf sdf s fsdfsdf
</span>
</label>
```

***Custom CSS solution:***

**By positioning your label tag with flex positioning**, you can easely have a vertical alignement for the input and the text using "align-items: flex-start;" :

```
<label class="my-label-class">
<input class="ml-2 mr-1 mb-1 inline-block" data-id="{{inputDataId}}" type="checkbox" class="{{class}}" {% if required %} required {% endif %}>
<span class="text-sm inline-block">
  {{label}}
</span>
</label>

.my-label-class {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

***Bootsrap solution***

**Or if you use Boostrap**, you can replace your Label tag classes by Boostrap ones:

```
 <label class="d-flex align-items-start">
```

Then your input and text will be aligned to top.

You can align them centered using "align-items-center"

Comment: this makes it look like the image in my post. I want the top line to be centered to the checkbox.

Comment: @Naomi Did you try "align-items-start" rather than "align-items-center" ?

Comment: Yes but it puts the label lower than the checkbox

Comment: Ok, then you can simply apply a  "margin-top: 5px;" to your input, or apply a smaller line-height to your label, like "line-height: 12px;"

Comment: You can also have a look to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/, in Checkboxes and radios section, there's example of checkbox code having the behavior you want to get.

Comment: Im using tailwind and not bootstrap.

Comment: ok, i just Edit my post with a Tailwind example that should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `flex items-top` to the wrapper and remove the `mb-1` of the input

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@0.5.2/dist/tailwind.min.css">


<label class="flex items-top">
        <input class="ml-2 mr-1 inline-block" data-id="{{inputDataId}}" type="checkbox" class="{{class}}" {% if required %}
    required {% endif %}>
        <span class="text-sm inline-block">
            Dsfsd fsdfsdfs fsdfsdfsd sdfsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf dsfsd fsdfsdfs fsdfsdfsd sdfsdfs 
            sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf dsfsd fsdfsdfs
            fsdfsdfsd sdfsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf dsfsd fsdfsdfs fsdfsdfsd sdfsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf
       </span>
    </label>
```

Comment: She wanted text and input aligned to top. Not centered.